# Probability mass function passport question

Tags: probability

Four passports are randomly returned to four students. let x be the number of students who receive their own passport. obtain the pmf of x.

The answer is p(4)=1/24, p(3) = 0, p(2) =1/4, p(1) = 1/3 and p(0) = 9/24

I just have the answer but I do not know how to get to these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose all four people correctly receive their passports. This happens only in one way, so the probability of this happening is $\frac 1{24}$, clearly.

Suppose three people correctly receive their passports. The fourth person can receive only the remaining passport, hence the correct one. Therefore, this can never happen.

Suppose that two people get their passports right. Choose these two people, this is done in $\binom 42$ ways. Now, the other two people's passports must be switched, since otherwise they would be correct. Hence, the number of ways of exactly two people getting their passports correctly is $\frac{\binom 42}{24} = \frac 14$.

Suppose that one person gets his passport right. Then, choose this person in one of $4$ ways. None of the others gets his/her passport correctly. Lets' call these people a,b,c, then a would get either b or c's passport in one of two ways, and then if he gets b's passport, then b gets c's passport and c gets a's. Similarly if a gets c's passport. So there are two ways of this happening, giving a total of $4 \times 2 = 8$. Hence, we get that the probability of this situation is $\frac{8}{24} = \frac 13$.

Finally, the only remaining possibility is that no one gets their passport, and the probability is $1 - \frac{1 +0+6+8}{24} = \frac{9}{24}$, as desired.